# combining 2 methods into a generic method in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to find a way to make this into one generic method, where I can either parse the value as a decimal or as an int. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

```
        private int ParseIntField(string value, int linecount, string fieldName)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out int result))
            {
                throw new Exception($"TryParse failed, line {linecount} Fieldname: {fieldName} Value: {value}");
            }
            return result;
        }

        private decimal ParseDecimalField(string value, int linecount, string fieldName)
        {
            if (!decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal result))
            {
                throw new Exception($"TryParse failed, line {linecount} Fieldname: {fieldName} Value: {value}");
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: why, though? it's working, it's clear enough, it's pretty short - making it generic for those two types would just make things more complicated.

Comment: Hard to imagine a situation where you might be required that method.

Comment: I'm a student, this isn't for practical reasons, I've be told to see if I can do it, and honestly I'm stumped.

Comment: Can't be done without using reflection to attempt to access the `TryParse` method on a generic type. Not sure what this is meant to accomplish, I'd go back to your tutor and call them out.

Comment: I agree, `TryParse` is anyway only available for a small number of types, so the benefit of generics isn't much

Answer (score 2):

There is no really good way to use a generic method for this, but you could perhaps split the method to share the common functionality, for example:

```
int? ParseInt(string s) => int.TryParse(s, out r) ? r : null;
decimal? ParseDouble(string s) => decimal.TryParse(s, out r) ? r : null;
T ParseOrThrow<T>(string str, int linecount, string fieldName, Func<string, T?> parser){
    return parser(s) ?? throw new Exception($"TryParse failed, line {linecount} Fieldname: {fieldName};
}
```

And called like `ParseOrThrow("5", 2, "five", ParseInt);`. But the benefit is probably marginal unless you have more code that needs to be shared between the different types.